# Como guardo los datos de un archivo en una variable o una matriz?

Tags: c++, archivo, variables, matriz

Este es el archivo .txt que tengo:
4 5 //Es el número de filas y columnas
0 1 0 0 0 /*
1 0 1 1 0  -Son los datos que se guardaran en la matriz
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 */
2 2 //Es la posición donde debo poner un objeto
1 3 //Es la posición donde debo poner otro objeto
Este es el código que tengo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void lectura();

int main(){
    lectura();
    
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void lectura(){
    ifstream archivo1;
    string linea;
    
    archivo1.open("Prueba 1.txt",ios::in); //Abrir el archivo en modo lectura
    
    if(archivo1.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while(!archivo1.eof()){  //Mientras no sea el final del archivo
        getline(archivo1,linea);
    
        cout<<linea<<endl;
    }
    
    archivo1.close(); //Cerrar el archivo   
}
```

Lo que necesito es saber como puedo guardar los datos en una variable o una matriz para poder manipularlos luego

Answer (score 0):

Primero decide qué quieres hacer con tus datos ya que dependiendo de lo que quieras, los deberás leer en una matriz o en otro tipo de dato.

Suponiendo que quieres números en una matriz de tamaño variable deberías empezar por definir ese tipo de matriz; te aconsejo usar `std::vector`:

```
using fila = std::vector<int>;
using matriz = std::vector<fila>;
```

Ahora, asumiendo que el formato de archivo es el que presentas (sin los comentarios):

> ```
> 4 5
> 0 1 0 0 0
> 1 0 1 1 0
> 0 0 1 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0
> 2 2
> 1 3
> ```

Podrías leerlo así:

```
matriz lectura(const std::string &ruta_archivo) {
    matriz resultado{};

    if (std::ifstream archivo{ruta_archivo})
    {
        int filas = 0, columnas = 0;
        archivo >> filas;
        archivo >> columnas;

        for (std::string linea; filas && std::getline(archivo, linea); --filas)
        {
            if (!linea.empty())
            {
                fila f;
                int valor;
                for (std::stringstream valores{linea}; valores >> valor; )
                    f.push_back(valor);

                resultado.push_back(f);
            }
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLRbtswDHyWvoLzgMAGmiDttpc4yzfsAwYUqiKnwmwpkCVjm@FvzyhKjr0UQQDzeKTuSMrrdStbYS6322dtZBvOCo7a9t4p0Z34gjUfoUFJb90a6WcSD702F2h0K@A79P58OCT2URt/qnO6E97pvw@EWIMMPlh9BuHkux5sWfGRM91ASUybxYAdix8uqDex8799MVWcMQvHIyu@wrefpsCQFXt4hn38zUAMnyO4MDJnDfxX8gIvS/UX/Kz5xHmW36Lu4EQprel9soLyor@NC168Zg8VoIVc4lQfWi/OdpzQ6WJMz8ZyzbhuEO1hC4YTpMH2OLj9E0jbhs6kqMZ0ZsPplFgP2EyP77LGuvxyVtxqo0Sd2282yc1F@YiXuctTYlU1bLdEjGOPwsjHJ0ruVHf1f8oqplKO0S00NX1HC4NorUvho4w8BGKofqSOUz3H0UUqBmqP9btr6N9f34T8VVKmIneM3ee8IjQVPTpx@uMakYX7M8tSaLlRYie0Sad3v8PYmOSmbYvgLWwaONyvYH2QZP8De0B2Q8rJsrTB483CUC9ScJHT7fYP)</kbd>.

Comment: Creo que te entendí para la matriz, pero si quisiera guardar por ejemplo el 4 y el 5 como dos datos tipo Int como lo podría hacer?

Comment: La sexta y séptima línea de la función `lectura` que he escrito lee las filas y las columnas en variables de tipo `int`.